# Ansible : iterate over inventory groups

Tags: docker, ansible, nested-loops, ansible-2.x

I have group `tgt-cluster` includes 3 hosts. I have written down role to deploy container which is executing on `tgt-cluster` group. I am controlling the number of containers to deploy with `with_sequence`. My tasks looks like this.

```
- name: Deploy Container 
  docker_container:
    name: "C{{ item }}"
    image: "{{ image_name }}:{{ image_tag }}"
    recreate: yes
    detach: yes
    tty: yes
    interactive: yes
  with_sequence: count="{{ number_of_container_to_deploy }}"
```

If I want to deploy one container, currently playbook is executing on all 3 hosts in `tgt-cluster` group and I end up with 3 containers. So How should I created nested loop in this case to control the task execution on hosts on round robin fashion.

Say if we want to deploy 4 container..
1st container should be deployed on 1st host in group, 
2nd container should be deployed on 2nd container in group, 
3rd should be deployed on 3rd hosts in group and 4th container should be deployed back to the 1st host in group.

I have updated my variable file with following, and `count_per_hosts` variable is assigned to `with_sequence`. While executing I was getting error stating "can't parse arg count=u'' as integer". So I updated `with_sequence: count="{{ count_per_hosts | int }}"` and it's not throwing error but It is not executing tasking not skipping it.

```
the_hosts: "{{ groups['tgt-cluster']}}" 
num_hosts: "{{ the_hosts | length }}" 
count_per_hosts: > 
  "{% for x in range(number_of_container_to_deploy) %} 
    - set idx = x % num_hosts 
      set cc = assignment.get(the_hosts[idx], 0) 
      set _ = assignment.update({the_hosts[idx]: cc + 1}) 
  {% endfor %}"
```

Currently my execution looks like this. `deploy_container : Deploy Process` tasks should create container but we don't see any logs over there. 
Also, I tried to move `the_hosts` and `num_hosts` inside `count_per_hosts` same syntax as indicated in answers but execution does not spill any output.

```
PLAY [bin installation] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [deploy_container : Deploy Process] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/tg/Documents/playbooks/roles/deploy_container/tasks/main.yml:3
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
br1.lab            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
br2.lab            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
br3.lab            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Also, I tried `default(0)` but ansible is throwing error. 
`{
    "msg": "can't parse arg count=u\"#' #  ' idx = x % num_hosts\\ncc = assignment.get(the_hosts[idx], 0)\\n_ = assignment.update({the_hosts[idx]: cc + 1})\\nidx = x % num_hosts\\ncc = assignment.get(the_hosts[idx], 0)\\n_ = assignment.update({the_hosts[idx]: cc + 1})\\n'\\n\" as integer"
}`

Current playbook looks like this,

```
- name: bin installation
  hosts: tgt-cluster
  user: "{{ user }}"
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars:
    count_per_hosts: |
      {% set the_hosts = groups["tgt-cluster"] %}
      {% set num_hosts = the_hosts | length %}
      {% set result = {} %}
      {% for x in range(number_of_process_to_deploy) %}
      {%   set idx = x % num_hosts %}
      {%   set h   = the_hosts[idx] %}
      {%   set cc  = result.get(h, 0) %}
      {%   set  _  = result.update({h: cc + 1}) %}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ result }}
  roles:
    - deploy_container
```

output with `with_sequence: count="{{ count_per_hosts }}"` if we specify `with_sequence: count="{{ count_per_hostsget(ansible_hostname, 0) }}"` we get `fatal: [br1.lab]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'ansible_hostname' is undefined"}`

```
TASK [deploy_container : Deploy Process] ***************************************************************************
fatal: [br1.lab]: FAILED! => {"msg": "can't parse arg count=u\"{u'br1.lab': 1, u'br2.lab': 1}\" as integer"}
fatal: [br2.lab]: FAILED! => {"msg": "can't parse arg count=u\"{u'br1.lab': 1, u'br2.lab': 1}\" as integer"}
fatal: [br3.lab]: FAILED! => {"msg": "can't parse arg count=u\"{u'br1.lab': 1, u'br2.lab': 1}\" as integer"}
```

I tried to register the output and check and ran `debug` on that to see the content and found it's not able to pick the host from group.

`ok: [br1.lab] => {
    "my_content": {
        "changed": false,
        "results": [],
        "skipped": true,
        "skipped_reason": "No items in the list"
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You will be much happier just doing the count assignment by yourself:

```
vars:
  the_hosts: "{{ groups['tgt-cluster']}}" 
  num_hosts: "{{ the_hosts | length }}" 
  count_per_hosts: |
    {% set result = {} %}
    {% for x in range(number_of_container_to_deploy) %}
    {%   set idx = x % num_hosts %}
    {%   set h   = the_hosts[idx] %}
    {%   set cc  = result.get(h, 0) %}
    {%   set  _  = result.update({h: cc + 1}) %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ result }}
```

Then in the actual `docker_container:` task, you are now able to have the `with_sequence:` be a count per host, and some of them may be zero:

```
- name: Deploy Container 
  docker_container:
    name: "C{{ item }}"
    image: "{{ image_name }}:{{ image_tag }}"
    recreate: yes
    detach: yes
    tty: yes
    interactive: yes
  with_sequence:
    count: "{{ count_per_hosts.get(ansible_hostname, 0) }}"
```

Comment: I have added loop in variable file as below,
`the_hosts: "{{ groups['tgt-cluster']}}"
num_hosts: "{{ the_hosts | length }}"

count_per_hosts: >
  "{% for x in range(number_of_container_to_deploy) %}
  -  set idx = x % num_hosts
     set cc = assignment.get(the_hosts[idx], 0)
     set  _ = assignment.update({the_hosts[idx]: cc + 1})
   {% endfor %}"`

`count_per_hosts` variable is assigned to `with_sequence`, however I am getting error stating `"can't parse arg count=u'' as integer"`

Comment: I can't read your formatting; can you update your question with it? but, based on  the error message you provided, it seems your `count=` in the sequence is resolving to the empty string, which presumably it would do if the current host isn't in the assignments; `count={{ whatever_you_have | default(0) }}` could solve that, or you can update your jinja code to just go ahead and initialize all hosts to have a zero count

Comment: I think I fell into a trap that I often do: I _presumed_ you were familiar with jinja2 and just needed a little nudge. I'll update the answer with a little more specifics

Comment: Sure, that would be more helpful.!

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks for updating answer in detail. I have updated the variable file and `with_sequence` exactly as per updated answer , ansible is throwing this strange error. 

`fatal: [br1.lab]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'count_per_hosts' is undefined"
}` 

If I only keep `count: "{{ count_per_hosts }}"` then also we are getting same error.

Comment: Does your playbook contain the `vars:` block in the first part of the answer? or, if it's a role, does your role contain a `vars/main.yml` with just those keys? I am struggling with why you are struggling with these errors - I don't know how to make the answer clearer

Comment: apologies for delayed response, yes i have variable in defaults/main.yml. Also I tried `vars` block in playbook itself. posting my current playbook and it's output by updating question. So format can be readable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184975/discussion-between-tgcloud-and-matthew-l-daniel).