# How to iterate over inventory group in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have looked at some of the SO post that are similar to my question: [Ansible : iterate over inventory groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683136/ansible-iterate-over-inventory-groups), [Ansible iterate over hosts in inventory group set by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698210/ansible-iterate-over-hosts-in-inventory-group-set-by-variable) and others but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong:

Here is my inventory file:

```
[root@82c420275711 playbooks]# cat inventory.dev
#
#   - Comments begin with the '#' character
#   - Blank lines are ignored
#   - Groups of hosts are delimited by [header] elements
#   - You can enter hostnames or ip addresses
#   - A hostname/ip can be a member of multiple groups
[localhost]
127.0.0.1

[virtual_centers]
172.17.0.2
172.17.0.5
```

Here is the part of my playbook that is having trouble:

```
- name: "allow {{ item }} to allow port 514"
  firewalld:
    immediate: yes
    rich_rule: "rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"{{ item }}\" port protocol=\"udp\" port=\"514\" accept"
    permanent: yes
    state: enabled
  with_items: groups['virtual_centers']
```

Here is the error message I get when I run the playbook with that inventory file:

```
[root@82c420275711 playbooks]# ansible-playbook -i inventory.dev ./configure_syslog-ng_server.yaml
...
    TASK [allow {{ item }} to allow port 514] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=groups['virtual_centers']) => {"changed": false, "item": "groups['virtual_centers']", "msg": "ERROR: Exception caught: INVALID_ADDR: groups['virtual_centers']"}
```

What am I doing wrong here? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok I figured it out.  I needed to write that task like so:

```
- name: allow {{ item }} to allow port 514
  firewalld:
    immediate: yes
    rich_rule: "rule family=\"ipv4\" source address=\"{{ item }}\" port protocol=\"udp\" port=\"514\" accept"
    permanent: yes
    state: enabled
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['virtual_centers'] }}"
```